# Fast way to assign rows from one of two dataframes based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`. I want to assign `df[some_columns] = df[subset1]` when `df[id1] > df[id2]` and otherwise `df[some_columns] = df[subset2]`.

This seems so simple but the following code doesn't work:

```
ids = (df[id1] > df[id2]).all(1)
df[some_columns] = df[subset1]
df.loc[~ids, some_columns] = df.loc[~ids, subset2]
```

I end up with null values where the second assignments should happen! So I tried some tinkering with `mask`s and `where`s but ended up with the same problem.

I even tried `df[some_columns] = pd.concat((df.loc[ids, subset1], df.loc[~ids, subset2]))` and ended up with `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`.

Is there a canonical way of accomplishing the task I described?

EDIT:

Here is a complete example of what I am trying to do

```
test = pandas.DataFrame({'id1': [0, 1],
                         'id2': [1, 0],
                         'subset1': ['A1', 'A2'],
                         'subset2': ['B1', 'B2']})
ids = (test[['id1']] > test[['id2']]).all(1)
test.loc[['new']] = test[['subset1']]
test.loc[~ids, ['new']] = test.loc[~ids, ['subset2']]
```

The goal is to get `test[['new']]` to be a DataFrame with a column given by `['B1', 'A2']`. While I illustrated the problem with just one column for `ids`, `new`, `subset`, and `subset2`, I need this to generalize to arbitrary numbers of these columns.

Comment: Can you create a brief but complete example that shows your problem? For all we know, there is simply a typo in e.g. the `subset2` list.

Comment: The error from your concat attempt hints that the `subset1` list and the `subset2` list are not the same length.

Comment: They most certainly are the same length. I just checked. I'll work on a simple example

Comment: @9769953 I updated the description with an example.

Comment: Your example doesn't work: `ids = test[['id1']] > test[['id2']]` results in an error.

Comment: Agreed. If you know of a way to accomplish this in a way that works for two sets of columns, of equal length such as `['id1]` and `[id2]`, I would love to post that!

Comment: What should be the result of comparing two columns? A two-dimensional index array? Or a one-dimensional index array, with only True values if both columns *individually* compare equal across the subsetted dataframes? Could you give an example of that comparison with multiple columns and the expected result?

Comment: Agree with @9769953. What does it mean to compare `df[['id1', 'id3']] > df[['id2', 'id4']]`

Comment: Agreed. Needed `().all(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `df.values`, there is no error

```
df[["new"]] = np.where((df[["id1"]].values > df[["id2"]].values).all(1),
                     df[["subset1"]].T, df[["subset2"]].T).transpose()
```

```
>>> df
   id1  id2 subset1 subset2 new
0    0    1      A1      B1  B1
1    1    0      A2      B2  A2
```

*Updated according to @AlexEftimiades comments*

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work for df[['new']]. However, the idea of using numpy with values seemed like a good lead. After playing around with it, I found this mess seems to work in the same spirit as your answer.

`test[["new"]] = numpy.where((test[["id1"]].values > test[["id2"]].values).all(1), test[["subset1"]].values.T, test[["subset2"]].values.T).T`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as you expect, I just fixed the extra brackets. You can do:

```
ids = test['id1'] > test['id2']
test['new'] = test['subset1']

test.loc[~ids, 'new'] = test.loc[~ids, 'subset2']

print(test)

   id1  id2 subset1 subset2 new
0    0    1      A1      B1  B1
1    1    0      A2      B2  A2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need this to work *with* those extra brackets because the solution needs to work for multiple columns. I just posted a note explaining this. I reproduced your solution, but also found that adding the brackets back produced an error.

Comment: @AlexEftimiades please update your example for multiple columns. i'll update the ans.

Comment: Sure, I specified the goal was to make `test[['new']]` a Dataframe with the values shown and one column--not a Series.